# Informatica flat file

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am working on a flat file source. The column names in the source are in form of big questions so they include commas and other special characters as well in column names. Since it is .csv file so the columns are separated by commas for first few column names and for remaining column names which are in form of questions are placed in between double quotes and separated by each other by commas.  Now my doubt is while setting the file properties in PowerCenter Designer.

How do i define the column delimiters and as well as the row delimiters so as to read data by skipping the column names?

This is how my file looks:

```
Number,X,Y,Z,P,Q,R,S,"(A) 1. When you need to look for information about your different mall options, what level of importance do you place on the following information sources? (1- Not at all Important / 10 - Very Important)  Website","(A) 1. When you need to look for information about your different mall options, what level of importance do you place on the following information sources? (1- Not at all Important / 10 - Very Important)Website"
1,1,,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Which are your column names? What row delimeter do you have in the flat file?

Comment: These are all column names :-
c1-Number,
c2-X,
c3-Y,
c4-Z,
c5-P,
c6-Q,
c7-R,
c8-S,
c9 -"(A) 1. When you need to look for information about your different mall options, what level of importance do you place on the following information sources? (1- Not at all Important / 10 - Very Important) Website",
c10-"(A) 1. When you need to look for information about your different mall options, what level of importance do you place on the following information sources? (1- Not at all Important / 10 - Very Important)Website"  
The record starts from 1,1,,1,1,1,1,1,1,1. From col 9 onwards all are question

Comment: and row delimeter is Space?

Answer (score 1):

In advanced properties, set column delimeters as ",", Optional Quotes as "Double", and Number of initial rows to skip as "1".

Also, you have to change the row delimeter if it is other than newline.

Comment: But when I am trying to enter the delimiters you mentioned it's giving an error of invalid delimiter.

Comment: That's weird. Never got that error. Are you entering , as a delimeter right?

Comment: Yes I was trying to add in the column delimiter only

Comment: I am not able to post the screenshot here. But the properties which I had set is: Column Delimiters-",",  Optional quotes-double row delimiters-\012 LF(\n) ,remove escape row data-enabled ,number of rows to skip- 1. the error I am getting is :-The delimiters you have specified is not valid.

Comment: Also let me know if setting the properties in informatica wouldn't work than will writing batch scripts for it will work? Like say if a batch script can be written to append pipe as delimiters for source file? Any advice is highly appreciated. It's very critical for me to solve it by today.

Comment: So are you able to set pipe as a delimiter but not comma?

Comment: Yes when I am setting the delimiter to pipe manually and trying to load the data is getting populated as pipe is not used anywhere in data fields.

Comment: Still two observation:-1. Since my column names are lengthy itself so separating it with pipe delimiter also didn't work as informatica has some line sequential buffer length limit while reading                                        2. when I tried to load the file removing all the column names and giving only data separated by pipe.It worked but than I can't do it manually for all source files.

Comment: Try increasing the line sequential buffer length in session properties.

Comment: I tried that also by giving value 100000 in the line sequential buffer length but still some column names are being populated in the row and the first column row is not getting skipped, thereby populating wrong data in the table.

Comment: As an alternative you can remove the first line using script and run it as a pre-session command.

Comment: I have no idea on how to write a script for it. Can you suggest me on how can I achieve this.

Comment: Assuming your Informatica server is running on Unix/Linux, you can use the command `sed '1d' original_file_name>new_file_name`.  It will create a new  file after removing the first line.